# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined ? Jest / React Native

Tags: react-native, unit-testing, jestjs, react-native-swiper

I have an image slider component to display images from my Firebase database as follows ,

```
import React from 'react';
import Swiper from 'react-native-swiper';
import { View, StyleSheet, Image } from 'react-native'


const ImageSlider = ({images}) => {
    return (
        <Swiper autoplayTimeout={5}
            style={styles.wrapper}
            showsButtons={false}
            loadMinimal={true}
            showsPagination={true}
            paginationStyle={styles.paginationStyle}
            activeDotStyle={styles.activeDotStyle}
            dotStyle={styles.dotStyle}
            loop={true} autoplay={true}
        >
            {images.map((data, index) => {
                return (
                    <View key={index} style={styles.slider}>
                        <Image style={styles.itemImage} source={{ uri: data }} />
                    </View>
                )
            })}
        </Swiper>
    )
}
```

For test above component I used follwing test file ,

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import ImageSlider from '../../../src/components/imageSlider/ImageSlider';


test('renders correctly', () => {
  const tree = renderer.create(<ImageSlider />).toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

When I'm run npm test command and after I got following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

Can anyone help me to slove this problem , Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your test, you're creating an `ImageSlider` without any parameters:

```
<ImageSlider />
```

In `ImageSlider`, you try to map the property `images`:

```
images.map( //etc
```

Because you didn't pass in an `images` parameter/property, `images` is undefined when you try to map it. To solve, this pass in value for `images` in your test:

```
<ImageSlider images={YOUR_TEST_IMAGES_DATA}/>
```

The other option is to redesign `ImageSlider` so that it fails gracefully if `images` is undefined. But, then there wouldn't be much a point in doing the test (unless the test was to see what happens if no parameter is passed in)